# Plotting real time data from txt file on a remote computer with matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, real-time

I did a realtime application that plot data from a remote computer using python, paramiko and matplotlib, however I have to write it as an standalone application to be used in standard Windows.

I'm trying to replicate it with Matlab (but maybe is not the best) because I don't know how to connect via ssh to read in real time the .txt file to read and plot thermal data.

Any advise, or recommendation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well that's a tricky one as windows doesn't have ssh.  I usually use putty for that.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

And then you can call 'system' from within Matlab:

```
    command = 'putty.exe -ssh server1.com';
    system(command)
```

bit hacky but....

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/system.html